# Get user whose interests matching with a event's interests

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want the list of Users whose interests match with a particular Event's interests. A user or event can have multiple interests like Social, Cultural, etc.

I have tried the below query to get the user(volunteers) list but it isn't dynamic for my application as an Event can have 1 or more interests. The below query will work only for 2 interests.

```
SELECT a.user_id 
FROM user_interests a, user_interests b 
WHERE 
    a.user_id = b.user_id 
    AND a.interest = 'Social'
    AND b.interest = 'Technical';
```

Each event will have no of volunteers required for the event. Suppose there is an event with interests (a,b,c).
So first the application will search for volunteers with all the interests (i.e a,b,c). If the required no of volunteers are not found then it will search for users having interests (a or b or c).

My schema is:

```
user(id,name,..)
user_interests(id, user_id, interest)
event(id,name,..)
event_interests(id, event_id, interest)
```

So please suggest me how to write the query for my above situation so that it is dynamic and I get the list of `user_id` having the matching interests.

I am building the application on Laravel 5.7. So laravel based queries or RAW SQL queries are also welcome.

PS: I'm a beginner so please let me know if I'm doing this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM user_interests
WHERE interest IN ('Social', 'Technical')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

This assumes that (user_id, interest) tuples are unique in table user_interest. If that’s not the case, you can change COUNT(*) to COUNT(DISTINCT interest).

Comment: Thanks a ton! Helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find  volunteers, ordered by number of matching interests, then:

```
SELECT ui.user_id 
FROM user_interests ui join
WHERE ui.interest IN ('Social', 'Technical')
GROUP BY ui.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT <n>;
```

You can extend the `IN` list to get more interests.